# What is performance efficient way to update the two interconnected table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've the following tables:
[image]

And I have an XML files with list of items and prices, like following:

```
<Item>
      <PriceUpdateDate>2014-03-08 22:25:29</PriceUpdateDate>
      <ItemCode>7290100701799</ItemCode>
      <ItemType>0</ItemType>
      <ItemName>Table salt 1 kg</ItemName>
      <ManufacturerName>unknown</ManufacturerName>
      <ManufactureCountry>unknown</ManufactureCountry>
      <ManufacturerItemDescription>Table salt 1 kg</ManufacturerItemDescription>
      <UnitQty>unknown</UnitQty>
      <Quantity>0.00</Quantity>
      <UnitOfMeasure>unknown</UnitOfMeasure>
      <bIsWeighted>0</bIsWeighted>
      <QtyInPackage>0</QtyInPackage>
      <ItemPrice>1.40</ItemPrice>
      <UnitOfMeasurePrice>0.0000</UnitOfMeasurePrice>
      <AllowDiscount>1</AllowDiscount>
      <ItemStatus>1</ItemStatus>
      <ItemId>1023201</ItemId>
    </Item>
```

I want to parse this file and add add new price record in **ItemPriceUpdates** if there's record of such item in **ItemsEAN13** or insert a new record in **ItemsEAN13** and then insert **ItemPriceUpdates**. The file is pretty big, more than 100000 records so I think it should be done in a few queries (by using batch updates like described here [JDBC PreparedStatement example – Batch Update](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)) , but in PostgreSQL I can't update two tables in a single query. So I'm looking a performance efficient way to achieve this.

Until now I thought about the following options:

1. Make a single table, it breaks normalisation principles (not good)
2. Split into multiple queries, very big drawback in a performance (not good)
3. Make two loops (drawback in performance, not good)
4. Using the **Stored Procedures**, I've never used it before and have heard that I should avoid to use it if it's unnecessary. (not sure that it's necessary in a current case)

So, I'm looking for advice how to do it correctly? I'm using PostgreSQL database.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a bulk upload - do what you should always do.

1. Parse the file and upload to two temporary tables
2. Update the target tables based on those

The temporary tables can be actually "temporary" as in "CREATE TEMP TABLE" or unlogged or just plain tables if you need.

Step 2 should take place in a single transaction if you can afford to, it makes your error detection simple.

Comment: Thank you very much. It'll take few day to implement your solution and then will give feedback/accept your answer.